# How to store password in # format in SQL Server Management Studio for my ASP.NET web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, mssql-jdbc

I have an ASP.NET web project with web form. for my log in, I need to store user password in hashed format. And also retrieve the password when logging in.

My table has columns

```
username varchar(50) Primary key, 
mobile varchar(50),
pass varchar(50)
```

My C# code is

```
try
{
   Console.WriteLine("inside try");
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO signinup ([username], [mobile], [pass]) 
                                    VALUES (@username, @mobile, @pass)", con);

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernametextbox.Text.Trim());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobiletextbox.Text.Trim());
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", passwordtextbox.Text.Trim());

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();

   Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Response.Write("<script>alert('Error: " + ex.Message + "');</script>");
}
```

I tried this

```
string plainPassword = passwordtextbox.Text.Trim();
byte[] hashedPasswordBytes;

using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
{
  hashedPasswordBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainPassword));
}
             
string hashedPassword = BitConverter.ToString(hashedPasswordBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", hashedPassword );
```

And also this

```
string password = passwordtextbox.Text.Trim();
string hashedPassword = HashPassword(password);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", hashedPassword);

private string HashPassword(string password)
{
  using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
  {
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] hashBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
    string hashedPassword = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    return hashedPassword;
   }
}
```

But it's not working

Comment: Do you know that all these issues are already solved by the [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics) libraries?

Comment: Thanks to rainbow tables hashed passwords are not really any better than plaintext passwords. If you must use password authentication at least look into salt-and-hashing techniques, where each user's password gets hashed with their own unique salt value.

Comment: Also, you should specify correct data types and length/precision/scale when adding parameters to SqlCommands. [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) ...and... [AddWithValue is Evil.](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation of your problem than "But it's not working". At what point are the expected results different from your actual results, and what are your expected and actual results at that point. If you are getting an error, what is the exact error message.

Comment: Leading spaces in passwords can be significant. Don't trim them. Also, what do you mean by "Not working"? How is it failing for you? Finally, you should look into using the BCrypt package on Nuget, which makes some of this easier and stronger.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use on basic projects for myself an a small group, it is something? Just need to pass in an encryption key which you can get generated online.

```
public string? EncryptString(string key, string plainText)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        byte[] array;

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            aes.IV = iv;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public string? DecryptString(string key, string cipherText)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            aes.IV = iv;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```